# Makefile isn't working for cross compiling

Tags: linux, makefile, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile to an arm development board. The makefile is invoking the native (x86) compiler, but passing it options that only make sense to an ARM compiler. I have the beginning of my make file as: 
ARCH = arm
CC = arm-Linux-gnueabi-gcc

The error I keep getting is: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc error unrecognized command line option '-m64'

Comment: From your error message, I would say that the exact opposite is happening: your make file is calling  arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc with -m64, which is the option required for compiling for an x86_64 64-bit target. Are you compiling you own code, or an existing code you did not write ? would it be possible that the make file was written with an x86_64 target in mind, and that is does contain options that are making sense only for an x86_target ?  hint: look for the "-m64" string in the make file.  Is the code you are attempting to cross compile open source ? if yes, what is its name ?

Comment: I am using an existing makefile

Comment: m64 doesn't exist in my makefile

Comment: Is the make file using a CFLAGS variable that may already be set in your current environment?  Execute echo $CFLAGS  or rebuild using ARCH=arm CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc CFLAGS="" LDFLAGS="" make If CFLAGS is not being used, at the $(CC) commands in the make file in order to identify which equivalent environment variable by be used and would already be set in you current environment.

Comment: I have an if else loop where if ($(DEBUG), 1), than EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DDDC_DBG_PRINT=1, else EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DDDC_DBG_PRINT=0

Comment: What are the values for CFLAGS, LDFLAGS and EXTRA_CFLAGS in the shell environment ? see my previous comment.
What is the value of CFLAGS in your make file?

Comment: EXTRA CFLAGS += -I$(src)/$(SRC_DIR) \ -I$(src)/$(COMMON_INC_DIR) \ -I$(src)/$(ACEX_ROOT) \ -Wall